# Label in UITableViewCell subclass changes position

Tags: iphone, uitableview, subclass

I have made a prototype cell in Interface Builder. This prototype contains an imageview which should change size depending on the length of a string.
Therefore I have written a method in my subclass of UITableViewCell to calculate the width of the text string with a given font and set this width to the width of the imageview.
This works fine until I push to another view controller and then go back to my table view. Then the view has been repositioned about 20 pixels to the right.

Does anyone know why this happens? This even happens if I set the x-position to something static, e.g. 200.

**Update 1:**

In my `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I use my subclass of UITableViewCell, `DFolderCell`. This calls the method `- (void)updateIndicatorsCount:andStarred` which sets the value of the `count` and the `starred` label and makes those labels and the images `countIcon` and `starredIcon` the width to the width of `_count` and `_starred` with a given font.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"folderCell";
    DFolderCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[DFolderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    int index = indexPath.row;
    Folder *folder = (Folder *) [folders objectAtIndex:index];
    FolderIcon icon = (FolderIcon) folder.icon.intValue;

    cell.name.text = folder.name;
    cell.icon.image = [[DFolders sharedFolders] imageForFolderIcon:icon];

    int count = [[DDrafts sharedDrafts] amountOfDraftsInFolder:folder withType:DraftLoadTypeRecent];
    int starred = [[DDrafts sharedDrafts] amountOfDraftsInFolder:folder withType:DraftLoadTypeStarred];
    [cell updateIndicatorsCount:count andStarred:starred];

    return cell;
}
```

The method below is part of my subclass `DFolderCell`

```
/* Update size of count and starred indicators */
- (void)updateIndicatorsCount:(int)_count andStarred:(int)_starred
{
    UIFont *badgeFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];

    UIImage *background;

    _count = 1000; // Test

    if (_count > 0)
    {
        self.count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _count];

        CGSize size = [self.count.text sizeWithFont:badgeFont];

        CGRect frame = self.countIcon.frame;
        frame.size.width = size.width;
        frame.origin.x = 320 - 20 - size.width;
        self.countIcon.frame = frame;
        self.count.frame = frame;

        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Folders_Badge_Count.png"];
        self.countIcon.image = [background stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:2 topCapHeight:2];

        self.count.hidden = NO;
        self.countIcon.hidden = NO;
    }

    /* Code for _starred is similar to code for _count */
}
```

This is the result.

This is how it should always look (and how it looks before selecting a cell)

[image: Before going back]

When a cell has been selected, a new viewcontroller has been pushed onto the navigation stack and I have popped this view controller by going back, this is how it looks.

[image: After going back]

**Update 2:**

I have kept the imageview in the cell prototype but commented out the code setting its size and its image to a stretchable image. I have also changed the background color of the label to a solid red to see the exact size of the label. The size seems to be correct.

This is my `- (void)updateIndicatorsCount:andStarred:` method now.

```
- (void)updateIndicatorsCount:(int)_count andStarred:(int)_starred
{
    UIFont *badgeFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];

    // UIImage *background;

    _count = 1000;

    if (_count > 0)
    {
        self.count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _count];

        CGSize size = [self.count.text sizeWithFont:badgeFont];

        CGRect frame = self.countIcon.frame;
        frame.size.width = size.width;
        frame.origin.x = 320 - 30 - size.width;
        self.count.frame = frame;
        self.count.hidden = NO;
        self.count.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        /* DON'T DO ANYTHING TO THE IMAGE */
        /*
         background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Folders_Badge_Count.png"];
         self.countIcon.hidden = NO;
         self.countIcon.image = [background stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:2 topCapHeight:2];
         self.countIcon.frame = frame;
        */
    } 
}
```

Before pushing to another view controller:

[image: Before pushing]

After going back from the view controller:

[image: After going back]

Comment: Can you show the code where you do this? And what method is it being done in?

Comment: @Jim I have updated the answer to show code.

Comment: @occulus I have updated the answer to show two images (before and after pushing and then going back)

Comment: I see you're setting the background image for your label. That's good, but for such a problem I would cancel this for a while and just set a background color, so I could see the actual size of the label (with an image they can "disagree"). But I'd say interesting bug :)

Comment: @makaron I don't set a background image for a label. It's a UIImageView beneath the label. I have tried keeping this imageview in the cell prototype but removing the code which sets its size and image to a stretchable image. I have also tried giving the label a red background color to see its exact size. The size seems to be correct. I have updated my question to show the code as it is now and new screenshots of the app.

Comment: I have ended up subclassing `UITableViewCell` and draw the content view myself. This works and I also believe this will give the best performance since I can use `- (void)drawRect` by doing so. If anyone knows a proper fix to this, please leave an answer as others might visit the question in hope to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your `cellForRowatindexpath` it will solve your issue

```
[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```